# How to open a popup when arriving from an external link

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Here is the current scenerio

I have a lightbox popup on "Site A" I want to link to "Site A" from "Site B" including the popup. WHart I mean is I want when the visitor arrives at the site from the external link to have the popup automatically appear wihtout the need to click the popup trigger.

I have tried utilizing the #popup-name within the href of the popup as well as the links however this is not solving the issue, I think due to the div ID still being set to display:none in the css which is altered in javascript when the user clicks the popup target.

Is there a way to successfully do this or am I paddling against the rapids right now?

Comment: Whenever you load the page check the URL for the hash value. If the hash meets certain requirements, open the modal. Or if your modal can be shown and hidden with only a CSS class or property, check out the `:target` pseudo selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out and hope the information I provide is helpful to anyone who is in the same issue.

What I had to do was integrate a new javascript which when the document loads checks that there is a specific hash within the URL. This way I can utilize this process for any one of the number of popups that I have on the site.

Here is the script that I used.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf("anchorhash") > -1) {
        $("#anchorhash").fancybox().trigger('click');
    }
 });
```

Basically here is whats happening

When the document loads we call the script and check the window for the correct hashtag url. If the url is correct we then call the chosen lightbox and treat the URL as the acceptance of a click on that popup link itself; which in return displays the popup on page load.

Hope this helps the community, I know it helped me.